# AJAX is not receiving data on success, it shows the result as "undefined"

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

This is jQuery code snippet is not getting valid data through AJAX and keeps updating data in divs as `undefined`. I don't know what the problem is.

```
function success(data) {
    alert(data.amount);
    $('#summary').html(data.count + "|" + data.amount);
};

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#button1").click(function (evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        var $form = $("#form1");
        $.ajax({
            type: $form.prop('method'),
            url: $form.prop('action'),
            data: $form.serialize() ,
            datatype: "json",
            tradition: true,
            success: function(data) {
                success(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

If I modify following success function to simply load a new page that shows the correct results that Action returns

```
function success(data) {
    $('#summary').html(data);
};
```

This is the controller action code snippet that receives the form fields data (id and quantity) from the view and returns `count` and `amount`:

```
public JsonResult AddtoCartDt(string id,string quantity)
{
    int id2 = int.Parse(id);
    Product pro = Data.Products.Single(c => c.Id == id2);
    var cart = ShoppingCart_BusinessLayer.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
    int l = int.Parse(quantity);
    for (int i = 0; i < l; i++)
    {
        cart.AddToCart(pro);
    }
    var Cart = ShoppingCart_BusinessLayer.GetCart(this.HttpContext);
    cartSummary summ = new cartSummary()
    {
        amount = Cart.GetTotal(),
        count = Cart.GetCount()
    };
    return Json(summ, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Comment: On the server side, does `summ` contain actual values?

Comment: Your javascript looks correct.  Do you also get undefined when running `$('#summary').html(data);`?

Comment: Are you running this code on a local server, or Firefox? It won't work otherwise.

Comment: yes summ contain actual values. Scott

Comment: Yes if use $('#summary').html(data); i get Undefined values Scott

Comment: yes m running on local server and chrome. Mottie

Comment: Its `traditional: true,` not `tradition: true,` but you can delete it anyway since you serializing the form.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine, but you should add some debug statements to check the response.

For starters, you could pass the `success` method directly as your `ajax` `success` handler, and add an error handler to log out any error:

```
$.ajax({
    type: $form.prop('method'),
    url: $form.prop('action'),
    data: $form.serialize() ,
    datatype: "json",
    traditional: true,
    // no need for the function()...
    success: success,
    error: console.log
});

// Alternatively, you could chain it:
$.ajax(/*...*/).done(success).fail(console.log);
```

That will call pass the `JSON` response as your `success` method parameter.

Then, try to add a `console.log()` statement to debug the response in the console:

```
function success(data) {
    console.log(data);
    $('#summary').html(data.count + "|" + data.amount);
};
```

**Edit**

Check the `tradition` parameters in your `ajax` call. [In the doc](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) it's called `traditional`.
Also, check the `route name` and `http` method in your controler.
You may want to add something like this in your controller:

```
[Route("~/myroute"), HttpPost]
public JsonResult AddtoCartDt(string id,string quantity)
{
  /*
  */
}
```